# React.js only reading first if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a textbox that either handlesclick on enter or changes text to SVG on space click. However, react is only considering the first if statement, using else works, but else if gets completely ignored.

textbox code:

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" contentEditable="true" className="grinputbox"
    onChange={(e) => {setInput(e.target.value)}}
    onKeyPress={twoCalls}
/>
```

TwoCalls function:

```html
const twoCalls = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        console.log("enter");
        handleClick()
    } else if (e.key === "Space") {
        console.log("space");
        toSVG()
    }
}
```

It does console log enter on pressing enter, however no space on pressing space

Comment: Note that `keypress/onkeypress` are deprecated, according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event. It would be better to switch to using [`keydown/onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such `key` property as `"Space"`. The value to check against for a user's press on the space key is a literal space character: `" "`. You can find this directly from https://keycode.info/ (press space), or indirectly from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) documentation. (The part that says "If the pressed key has a printed representation, the returned value is a non-empty Unicode character string containing the printable representation of the key.")

So in short, replace

```
else if (e.key === "Space" )
```

with

```
else if (e.key === " " )
```

Answer (score 1):

- There's deferant between `e.key`, `e.code` in `key` some browser return space as `" "` and in some old browsers return it as `"Spacebar"` if you want the most support for space with `key` you can make it like the following

```
if(e.key === "Enter") {
  //Some code
} else if(e.key === " " || e.key === "Spacebar") {
 //Some code
}
```

- on the other side there's also `e.code` who will return space as `Space` if you want to use `Space` you can make your code like that

```
if(e.key === "Enter") {
  //Some code
} else if(e.code === "Space") {
 //Some code
}
```

- but for better support use `e.key` [here's a list with key values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values)
- also there's some other things like `e.keyCode` who is deprecated so avoid use it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of this:
`e.key === 'Space'` it should be `e.key === 'Spacebar'`.

Comment: Spacebar is used only by some antique browsers, according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values